# How to you see if other players have overpower levels in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is there any possible way to tell if another player joining your server has overpower levels, without having to ask them?

Also, is there a way of telling by joining their server, seeing if the host has overpower levels?

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an older question recently modified, but there's no good answer so here goes. I have been playing FAR too much Borderlands 2 recently.

There is no way to tell directly if a player joining your server has OP levels. If your concern is a higher OP making your enemies more difficult, don't worry. The OP of a room is determined by the host, and not subject to change by higher OP characters. If you open an OP2 room and an OP8 person joins, you are still in an OP2 room, and their OP levels won't raise enemy levels, even in Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode (of course, you can't even open an OP room in Normal or True Vault Hunter Modes).

If you are looking to trade gear, the only reliable way to find OP levels is to ask. If you have voice and the other person doesn't, just ask him to trade with you and show you a weapon that's at his level. Or type, but that's slow.

Now, if you are JOINING a room, you can tell what OP the room is by checking the products available on a vending machine. The highest OP or level piece of gear you find for sale is the OP of the room you joined.

Hope that helps, however belatedly!

Answer (score 0):

No there is not except by looking at the enemies lv if they are about 68-74 it is on OP0 and if it is higher it is OP1+ but can't help you past there

Comment: Generally, we're looking for answers that are more than just a single sentence.  Expand on your statement.  If someone has to look at the enemies' level, how does that help them see other player's overpower levels?